# Laravel 6.x relationship default value on first relation

Tags: php, laravel

I want to set a default value for the first relation element and after that another. For example:

Customer can have multiple addresses.
The addresses table has the column main_address.
When I create a customer and the first address for him, Laravel should then give the column main_address the value 1. The second should get the value 0 (if not specified different).

Is Laravel capable of doing this?

My creating prozess of a customer is the following:

```php
$customer = \App\Customer::create(["data"]);
$customer->customerAddress()->create(["data"]);
$customer->contactPerson()->create(["data"]);
```

Can this prozess be improved?

The relations are both Many to one. A customer can have multiple contact persons and addresses.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
$customer = \App\Customer::create(["data"]);
$address = $customer->customerAddress()->create(["data"]);

$main_address_exists = $customer->customerAddress()->where('main_address', 1)->first();

    if (!$main_address_exists) {

        $address->main_address = 1;
        $address->save();

    }
```

So you first check whether this customer has an address with field main_address, 1 and if it doesn't have any such record it will make the last address as 1

OR

```
$customer = \App\Customer::create(["data"]);

    $data_for_addresses = [
        'main_address' => 0
    ];

    $main_address_exists = $customer->customerAddress()->where('main_address', 1)->first();

    if (!$main_address_exists) {

        $data_for_addresses['main_address'] = 1;

    }

   $customer->customerAddress()->create($data_for_addresses);
```

Comment: Is is possible to inject that in the create function in the model?

Comment: Check another option I have added in the above answer